# The command 'pip freeze' on the linux bash shell is not showing any of the installed packages in the output

Tags: python, django, linux, bash

I'm using the Linux Bash shell on Windows to activate django virtual environment and I want to see if the packages I'm using in this certain project are showing up using `pip freeze` *(just like in the tutorial I am watching, since I'm very new to Linux in general)* but once I put in the command, it doesn't give me any errors it's just that it won't output any packages at all. This might be a very simple question to some of you guys but I was doing some research and I can't find anyone in the exact same circumstances I'm in, so I decided to come to SO for help.

[image: the console]

```
(djangoenv) winston1420@DESKTOP-PS608FU:/mnt/c/Users/admin/desktop/first_djangoproject_venv$ pip freeze +pip freeze
```

As you can see in the image, or code, it only shows the `+ pip freeze`. Please, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Can you add the output of two commands to your question, `python --version` and `pip --version`? Also, how did you create and activate your `venv`?

Comment: @FlipperPA I have **Python 3.9.6** and **pip 21.3**. And I created my ```venv``` by first creating a folder inside my django project called **django_env** and then using the *bash shell* y used the ```cd``` command into the folder I created previously, and then I typed ```python3 -m venv djangoenv``` to create the environment and lastly ```source djangoenv/bin/activate``` to activate said environment. The steps I followed are shown here https://www.javatpoint.com/django-virtual-environment-setup

Answer (score 1):

This is what fixed it for me:

After I used the commnad `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`, the packages are showing up when using the `pip freeze` command.

Comment: Huh, that is odd, but I’m glad you figured it out.